# Android force close on split() function

Tags: java, android, split

I am using an android emulator for testing and when it was carrying out this function, it force closed the application. However, the function was carried out successfully and produced the toast message `(E.g. String1|Sub1,Sub2,Sub3)` after I've commented away the following statements. When I un-commented the first split() statement and tried a test run, it force closed the application again.

```
public void readData()
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("data.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;

        do 
        {
            line = br.readLine();

            //String[] temp = line.split("|");
            //String[] temp2 = temp[1].split(",");

            //Vector<String> nameTemp = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(temp2));

            //Team container = new Team(temp[0], nameTemp);
            //grpContent.add(container);

            invalidCharacterToast(line);    //Toast message
        }
        while (line != null);

        br.close();
        isr.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.example.project.Start.readData(Start.java:196)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.example.project.Start.onClick(Start.java:140)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-27 12:13:41.446: E/AndroidRuntime(289):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 12:13:43.406: I/Process(289): Sending signal. PID: 289 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can you please share logcat?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your "force close". If you do not understand what the stack trace is telling you, edit your question and paste in that stack trace.

Comment: you should check if line is != null

Comment: Just to add to everyone else's suggestions -- Make sure that temp has more than one element so that when you reference temp[1] it isn't an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Looks like line is null. else you should not be getting a crash in `split()`

Answer (score 4):

This is a do-while loop, so your `br.readLine()` statement is executed before the null check, so the first `split` method might be executed against `null`.

You should rewrite it as such:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. However, if the first split method is executed against null, why did the toast message appears successfully with the String that is being read from the file?

Comment: @Mena: I suspect that you mean that the *last* `split()` method *will* be executed against `null` (otherwise, this would be an infinite loop).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your observation! Actually I meant the _first_ of the two `split()` methods. The null pointer could either happen if the very first `readLine()` call returned `null`, or as you mention, when the last line is read, and therefore `null` is returned.

Comment: @jl90 as CommonsWare mentions (see also my caveat), it could be that the first `Toast` (s) executed OK because the lines were not `null`. At some point, however, the line _will_ be `null`, but there will still be an iteration of the loop executed before exiting said loop, hence the NPE...